# How to efficiently check against bitmask?

Tags: c++, c, bit, bitmask

I am using inotify and want to efficiently check against the reported bitmask event (see [inotify man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify)).

Now I could brutely check against every bit on every event, but that would be extremely crude, if not stupid, as I would have N conditionals every time. Or is calling

```
( bitmask & mask ) == mask
```

for **each** mask already super efficient?

Since the resulting bitmask is basically just a well defined number, I should be able to use basic arithmetic operations for this. But before I think up something myself, I wanted to ask if there is a well-known, efficient way to check against a given bitmask. So, is there?

Comment: Can you please clarify what the input and output are (in particularly what the input is)?

Comment: If you want to have different behavior for each mask, you'll have to check for each one individually. If you want to know whether a group of masks matches you can | them.

Comment: Also `(bitmask & mask) == mask` is a bit redundant. If the masked bit was true, it'll boil down to `true == true`

Comment: @Ari You need to compare against mask, otherwise you get incorrect results when mask is 0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to check against *one* bitmask, then

```
if ((value & mask) == mask)
```

will give you an exact match ("all bits in the mask"), and

```
if ((value & mask) != 0)
```

will supply a loose match ("any bit in the mask"). The compiler will further optimize the check against zero.

If you have several bitmasks, you want to extract the maximum information out of each check in the time domain (an extreme case: if all the values you get are *certainly* odd, you needn't check the 0th bit at all. It will always be 1). Ideally you need to identify a first round of bits that have a 50% probability of being 1.

In both groups you then identify a subgroup (probably not the same in the two cases) with the same chance.

```
if ((value & SPECIAL_MASK_1) == SPECIAL_MASK_1) {
    if ((value & SPECIAL_MASK_2) == SPECIAL_MASK_2) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else {
    if ((value & SPECIAL_MASK_3) == SPECIAL_MASK_3) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you had, say, 32 states, each mapped to one bit, and only one bit can be set at each call - the easiest case - the "serial" sequence would be one of 32 checks one after the other

```
if ((mask & 0x00000001) == 0x00000001) {
} else if ((mask & 0x00000002) == 0x00000002) {
}
...
```

and a first simple optimization would to place the checks for the most frequent occurrences first. Say that one case out of three the seventh bit is set; you put the check for the seventh bit first.

This way you will end up doing only one check 33% of the time; then maybe two checks another 20% of the time, ..., and in the end **on average** you might run, say, seven checks.

Another possibility is

```
if (mask & 0x0000FFFF) {
    // The bit is in the LSW
    if (mask & 0x0000FF00) {
        // MSB of LSW
        if (mask & 0x0000F000) {
            ...
        } else {
        }
    }
} else {
}
```

This will run every time exactly five checks. At that point, however, considerations about the CPU architecture, branch prediction etc. are likely to trump any optimization you might attempt to do.

Unless you have a *very* complex setup, or some other constraint (e.g. embedded device), I fear that the cost of analyzing, building, debugging and maintaining an "optimized" versus "brute force" check is likely to more than balance any advantage you could squeeze out of the former.

Comment: "... the cost of analyzing, building, debugging and maintaining an "optimized" versus "brute force" check is likely to more than balance any advantage you could squeeze out of the former." This is very reassuring. I think I will then stick to a more readable approach. Thank you for this excellent answer!

Answer (score 4):

For checking multiple bits of a mask I use a loop.  If you're using a decent compiler it should optimise the code fairly decently.  Unless you have significant performance problems, it's not worth hand-optimising as all the CPUs I know of implement a logical bit test or bit-wise AND operation in a single instruction.  So you have two instructions: the logic instruction and the CPU branch-condition instruction for each bit.  Not a massive amount of code to run and - as far as I know - impossible to beat.  (Note that since the `mask` is 32 bits wide, if you're running on a 16 bit core CPU, there will be a couple more instructions to test both halves.)

```
void processEvents(uint32_t events)
{
    uint32_t bitToTest;
    // Check each bit in turn
    for(bitToTest = 1; bitToTest < events; bitToTest << 1)
    {
        // Check which bit is set.  If none then the default case is used.
        switch(bitToTest & events)
        {
            case IN_ACCESS:
                // Handle the IN_ACCESS event flag here.
                break;
            case IN_ATTRIB:
                // Handle the IN_ATTRIB event flag here.
                break;
            // Et cetera...
            default:
                // No flag was set, so do nothing.
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could accept multiple answers... I ended up using a variant of your stub for my actual problem (inotify), but @lserni 's answer answered my general question extremely thoroughly, so credit were credit is due. But rest assured that you are at least the hero of my day! ;)

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one bit set and if your code doesn't have to be portable, you can use intrinsics that give you the position of the set bit and then use the result in a switch statement. 
For gcc that would e.g. be

```
__builtin_ffs
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is necessary to check against every bit mask, there is no other way than to check explicitly. However, if the specific bit masks are known, bitwise checks could be done, effectively resulting in ruling out half of the possible bit masks in every step.